# WAVE file extended part of fmt chunk

Tags: javascript, firefox, encoding, web-audio-api, wave

I have a WAVE file with a `wFormatTag` that is 3 (`WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT`). Firefox treats `WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT` files like `WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE`, which means that it expects that a `WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT` file contains the extended part of the fmt chunk.

My file doesn't contain the extended part of the fmt chunk, which results in an error when decoding the file in Firefox: `The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains invalid content which cannot be decoded successfully.`

This means I have to add `wValidBitsPerSample` at byte 38, `dwChannelMask` at byte 40 and `SubFormat` at byte 44. **What information should I be adding for those three header fields? What is the meaning of this information and how can I add them in the form of 8-16-32bits integers?**

Thanks for the help :).

Here is the header information of my file:

```
console.log('ckID', String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(0))); // R
console.log('ckID', String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(1))); // I
console.log('ckID', String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(2))); // F
console.log('ckID', String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(3))); // F

console.log('cksize', dataView.getUint32(4, true)); // 65623058

console.log('WAVEID', String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(8))); // W
console.log('WAVEID', String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(9))); // A
console.log('WAVEID', String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(10))); // V
console.log('WAVEID', String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(11))); // E

console.log('ckID', String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(12))); // f
console.log('ckID', String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(13))); // m
console.log('ckID', String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(14))); // t
console.log('ckID', String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(15))); //

console.log('cksize', (dataView.getUint32(16, true))); // 16

console.log('wFormatTag', (dataView.getUint16(20, true))); // 3

console.log('nChannels', (dataView.getUint16(22, true))); // 2

console.log('nSamplesPerSec', (dataView.getUint32(24, true))); // 44100

console.log('nAvgBytesPerSec', (dataView.getUint32(28, true))); // 352800

console.log('nBlockAlign', (dataView.getUint16(32, true))); // 8

console.log('wBitsPerSample', (dataView.getUint16(34, true))); // 32

console.log('cbSize', (dataView.getUint16(36, true))); // 0

console.log('ckID', String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(38))); // f
console.log('ckID', String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(39))); // a
console.log('ckID', String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(40))); // c
console.log('ckID', String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(41))); // t

console.log('cksize', (dataView.getUint16(42, true))); // 4

console.log('dwSampleLength', (dataView.getUint16(46, true))); // 10876

console.log('ckID', String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(50))); // d
console.log('ckID', String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(51))); // a
console.log('ckID', String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(52))); // t
console.log('ckID', String.fromCharCode(dataView.getUint8(53))); // a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1349658, Firefox doesn't support float32 WAV files.