# How to get a precise timeupdate on a video to return upto 2 decimal numbers (milliseconds)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a video element where I want to compare it's current time to a variable with upto 2 decimal values.

```
$(video1).on('timeupdate', function(){
    var currentTime = Math.round(this.currentTime);
    var durationNum = Math.round(this.duration);
    var formattedCurrentTime = secondsToHms(currentTime);
    var formattedDurationTime = secondsToHms(durationNum)
    onTrackedVideoFram(formattedCurrentTime, formattedDurationTime)

    if(currentTime >10){ $(".box1, .box2").hide(); }

    if(currentTime == choiceHeart){
        console.log("HERE");
        video1[0].pause();

    }
```

this is from a tutorial file so the only way I know how to get the timeupdate to return a value is through that math.round function which returns rounded whole number.

**BUT, I want to trigger an event, like pause the video at, say, 2.5 minutes** (or 2 minutes 15 frames - by After effects 30 fps standards)****

The way I could do is create a variable early in the document like this :

```
var triggerEvent = 2.5;
```

So how do I get to understand that 2.5 means to return this value in 2 minutes and half minutes and it should pause the video at 2 & a half minutes?

PS :

In order to pause the video I plan to use an if loop :

```
if(currentTime == triggerEvent){
    video1[0].pause();
}
```

here video1 is referencing to a variable which points to the div which holds the video.

Comment: `currentTime` of the video is in [units of seconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime). If you want to pause at 2.5 minutes, just do `currentTime >= 2.5 * 60`?

Comment: And if you dont need the math.round, why dont you leave it away??

Comment: I am learning, this code is copied from the exercise files. 
I want to do away with it but if I remove "math.round()" it doesnt work.

Comment: `timeupdate` does not dispatch linearly

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Media Fragments URI](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/) to play exactly the time slices that you request

> Normal Play Time can either be specified as seconds, with an optional
>   fractional part to indicate miliseconds, or as colon-separated hours,
>   minutes and seconds (again with an optional fraction).

For example, the code below will play ten seconds of the media before the `pause` event is dispatched at the `HTMLMediaElement`

```
 video.src = "/path/to/media#t=0,10"
```

See also

- [HTML5 audio streaming: precisely measure latency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768375/html5-audio-streaming-precisely-measure-latency/38842623?s=1|1.8900#38842623)
- [How to make range request for any portion of a media fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45024915/how-to-make-range-request-for-any-portion-of-a-media-fragment)

---

You can use  media fragment identifier `#t=00:00,02:30` concatenated to the `"src"` attribute value to make a range request for the specified temporal dimensions of the media resource.

When the media fragment identifier is set at the `"src"` attribute or `.src` property of the `HTMLMediaElement` and `.play()` is called, exactly two minutes and thirty seconds `02:30` of media will play, before the `.pause()` event is dispatched when `02:30` is reached, or `150` seconds

```html
<label></label><br>
<video 
  width="300" 
  height="200" 
  controls></video>
<script>
const video = document.querySelector("video");
const label = document.querySelector("label");
const src = "http://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ASharedCulture_480p.webm";
const timeSlice = "#t=00:00,02:30";
let raf;
video.src = src + timeSlice;
video.oncanplay = video.play;
video.onpause = function(event) {
  video.onmouseenter = video.onmouseleave = raf = null;
  // do stuff
  if (Math.floor(video.currentTime) === 60*2.5) {
    console.log(video.currentTime, video.currentTime/60);
  }
}
function update(t) {
  let curr = Math.floor(video.currentTime);
  let message = `${curr} seconds played, ${(60*2.5)-curr} to play before pause event`;
  label.innerHTML = message;
  raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

video.onmouseenter = function() {
  raf = requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
video.onmouseleave = function() {
  label.innerHTML = "";
  window.cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have no clue on how to use this .. I was just following a tutorial and trying to fork the exercise files.

Comment: @Logan _"I have no clue on how to use this"_ You asked the question  specific  to this very topic. Have you read the linked specification? See updated post for description of and demonstration of usage.

Answer (score 1):

You are rounding the variable used in the comparison...
Rounding gets the closer integer:

0.4 gives 0
0.6 gives 1

To get a floating number with two decimals, you can do this:

```
var currentTime = parseFloat(this.currentTime);
currentTime = parseFloat(currentTime.toFixed(2));
```

```js
var currentTime = 2.8349354;
currentTime = parseFloat(currentTime.toFixed(2));
console.log(currentTime);
```

So you can use just this:

```
var currentTime = parseFloat(this.currentTime.toFixed(2));
```

And the same thing for `durationNum` if you also need it to be a float with 2 decimals.

---

**EDIT**

You could also try this... It should work on all browsers.

```
var currentTime = Math.round(this.currentTime*100)/100;
```

Comment: This worked.. but only on Chrome not on Waterfox/firefox