# Make an audio sprite without loading the complete song

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, audio, howler.js

I'm using Howler JS to play songs on a website. I want just a portion of the song to be played.

Im making a sprite of each mp3 and those sprites can be played. However, it takes really long before the audio plays. It's like the whole mp3 is downloaded first and then the sprite begins, which really decrease performances and consume bandwidth. 
Im not familiar with Howler at all, maybe there's a method to download just the portion to be played, or if not, is there any other library/ ways to accomplish this ?

```
         <div
          className="playExtrait"

          onClick={() => {
            Howler.unload();
            let song = new Howl({
              src: [url],
              html5: true,
              sprite: {
                extrait: [0, 30000]
              }
            });

            let songID = song.play("extrait");
            setPlayPause("playing");
            song.fade(1, 0, 30000, songID);
            song.on("end", () => {
              setPlayPause("paused");
            });
          }}
        >
```

Comment: Do you have control over the media source? One approach would be to create a recording of the specific time slices of the media then request and playback that media fragment.

Comment: @guest271314 , the medias are in a firebase storage bucket. So , yes i guess....

Comment: @guest271314 how can i do this, in js / react ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create recordings of each specific time slices of the media by using [Media Fragments URI](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/), for example, by setting `src` of a `<audio>` element to  `/path/to/media#t=10,15` for playback of `10` through `15` seconds of the media resource and `MediaRecorder` to record the playback and save the recording as a `.webm` media file, where `MediaRecorder` is stopped at `pause` event of `HTMLMediaElement`.

See

- [How to edit (trim) a video in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806571/how-to-edit-trim-a-video-in-the-browser/)
- [How to get a precise timeupdate on a video to return upto 2 decimal numbers (milliseconds)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549552/how-to-get-a-precise-timeupdate-on-a-video-to-return-upto-2-decimal-numbers-mil/)
- [Javascript - Seek audio to certain position when at exact position in audio track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395073/javascript-seek-audio-to-certain-position-when-at-exact-position-in-audio-trac/)
- [How to use Blob URL, MediaSource or other methods to play concatenated Blobs of media fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217962/how-to-use-blob-url-mediasource-or-other-methods-to-play-concatenated-blobs-of)?

For an example of concatenating multiple media fragments into a single recording see [MediaFragmentRecorder](https://github.com/guest271314/MediaFragmentRecorder) (am the author of the code at the repository). `MediaSource` at Chromium/Chrome has issues when `MediaRecorder` is used to record a `MediaSource` stream, though the code should still produce the expected result at Firefox.